# Transfer entities to JSON format on Google Datastore

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to count how many Entities in my datastore, so I

```
const query = datastore.createQuery('testname','testkind')
    .filter('done', '=' , false) .order('innerID',{         descending:
true});

var dataList;

const rQuery = datastore.runQuery(query)

     .then((results) => {       dataList = results[0];      });
```

just an example that I use query to fetch the entities I want.

However, when I try to count how many entities are there, it's quite difficult. 
If I use `app.get('/', (req, res) => {   res.json(dataList); });`, it shows an normal form of JSON.

---

But, when I try to count the numbers outside the read request, 
`console.log(dataList);`

It shows `undefined`....

---

Then I tried 
`const par = JSON.parse(dataList); console.log(par);`

it shows `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

---

Any tips to solve this problem? or maybe I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, when I try to count the numbers outside the read request,

I think that's the problem. You'll have to wait for the variable to be populated before you can access it.